# Auto-arrange desktop icons in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: icons, 17.04

I know this is the same question as asked 6 years ago:  **[How to Auto-Arrange Desktop Icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47290/how-to-auto-arrange-desktop-icons)** 
But isn't there any solution available yet? I am clearly not asking about "Organize desktop by name".
**EDIT**: Consider an example for easy understanding: Consider some icons floating randomly on your desktop. This is what is the problem. Now you want them to arrange all of them in matrix of rows and columns. This is what I am asking for. The problem, as soon as you create a new file/folder, anywhere randomly on the desktop, it should be added only at the end of the matrix.

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) what you are asking about since you say you aren't asking about "Organize desktop by name". Arrange by what? why?

Comment: @ElderGeek Consider some icons floating randomly on your desktop. This is what is the problem. Now you want them to arrange all of them in matrix of rows and columns. This is what I am asking for. The problem, as soon as you create a new file/folder, anywhere randomly on the desktop, it should be added only at the end of the matrix.

Comment: Are you looking for Keep Aligned?

Comment: @subtleseeker Please [edit] your question to reflect all the details you posted in comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657)

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes, exactly!

Comment: so you dont want any alternative solution.. you want stright away in matrix.. rite??

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 18.04 Right-click on the desktop and select Keep aligned as shown below:

[image: keep aligned]

Be aware that if there are holes in the grid due to icons that you have deleted they will be filled first.

Comment: The holes are the real problem. I am aware of this method. I need "Keep aligned" that works at all times, ie. after deleting one icon or dragging some icon all the icons shift by 1, similar to what happens in windows.