# How do I organize desktop icons in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

I would like to know if there is any way possible to organize **Desktop Icons** in Ubuntu 20.04.
For example, if I delete certain icons from the desktop which were initially organized, there is no one-click way of aligning them back again.

[image]

Back in Ubuntu 17 I could do that following this method: https://askubuntu.com/a/925419/1098457
But after the upgrade, I could use a pointer as to how to achieve this. Thank you!